# Is sizeof(int) == sizeof(unsigned int) guaranteed by the standard?

Tags: c, integer, language-lawyer

Many programs assume `sizeof(int)==sizeof(unsigned int)` . IMO it is not and I cant find anything in the Standard which guarantees it. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: In the current [C23 draft](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3054.pdf) on page 22 it says "The macro INT_WIDTH represents the width of the type int and shall expand to the same value as UINT_WIDTH." So maybe they must be the same.

Comment: See 6.2.5 paragraph 6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C11 6.2.5.6 (Types) says "For each of the signed integer types, there is a corresponding (but different) unsigned integer type (designated with the keyword unsigned) that uses the same amount of storage (including sign information) and has the same alignment requirements."

Comment: “6.2.5.6” is not a proper way to cite paragraph 6 of clause 6.2.5 because that form fails to distinguish paragraph 1 of clause 6.3 (“6.3.1”) from clause 6.3.1 (also “6.3.1”).

Comment: hash collisions...